# How do I download programs on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I made the switch to Ubuntu Linux from Windows a few hours ago, and now, I am currently trying to download Anki, but I dont know how to do so because I do not know what to type in the terminal. Can someone please help?

Comment: Mostly, you don't.  The preferred method of installing programs is via the package manager, with manual installation as a method of last resort.

Comment: If you are just embarking on your Linux journey I will suggest you become much better friends with Google search.

Comment: Apparently, you want to jump into the deep end of the pool and learn everything Linux via the terminal.  That's great, and good luck.  Most other readers landing here coming from Windows typically want to get up and running quickly, and learn Linux over time so it isn't overwhelming. There's no need to use the terminal to install software if it's in the repository.  Ubuntu comes with at least one GUI package manager (which one varies with the particular version and DE).  That works similar to the Windows Store. You just search for the package and let the package manger install and maintain it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### I am currently trying to download Anki

Ubuntu uses `apt get` to download an install packages.

> **How To Install "anki" Package on Ubuntu**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update -y
> sudo apt-get install -y anki
> ```
>
> Execute the commands above step by step.
>
> Note: `-y` flag means to assume yes and silently install, without
>   asking you questions in most cases.

Source [How to install anki ubuntu package on Ubuntu 18.04/Ubuntu 17.10/Ubuntu 16.04](http://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/anki)

Comment: apt-get is to install packages from the ubuntu software app right? Anki from the software app doesnt work. Do you know how to install it once you download Anki from the site? The site tells you how to do so but what they tell you to type in the terminal doesnt install anki

Comment: @iamlearningtocode That would have been _very_ useful information to include in the question.

Answer (score 6):

So, let's tackle not only the situation "I need to install programX" (answer to which is `apt install programX`, but also "the version of programX in my Ubuntu repository does not work, but there is a working version out there".

## Keep calm and `apt update`

Basically, one could bank on the idea that a newer version will arrive to mainstream repo sooner or later and just wait.

Don't forget to update the package database per above before checking for the newer version.

## The proper way

It is not on Ubuntu. It is probably not on Debian stable or testing. But it might be on Debian unstable or Debian experimental. You basically need to extend your apt's `sources.list` with those repositories. It also makes your system a hybrid of Ubuntu und untested Debian packages, but it most cases it works fine.

A nice idea is to change pins and priorities of repositories so apt does not suck in half of Debian unstable at once just because it's newer.

## The fast and ugly way

If there is a pre-built debian package out there - this is the case in many not-quite-standard software, you can just download the package from the developer's website. Ubuntu / Debian is a very popular distro, so if there are binary builds for linux, there should be some `*.deb` packages

## The open source way

Build the package from source. There were some details in other answers, but as far as I have seen, not quite the Debian way. The `./configure && make && make install` leads to cluttered `/usr/local` where no one knows what depends from what and why it's there. Trust me, I've been there, did do that.

So, download the source, `./configure` (probably with `--prefix=/usr` and other package-dependent options), `make` (or `make -j12` for speed). Then, you can use the `checkinstall` script (and probably also `fakeroot`) to build a debian package. It will be installed automatically by `checkinstall`. There are other ways, start reading around `man dpkg`.

For building the software from source you need a toolchain and its dependencies. Google for `debian build essentials` and look up `apt build-deps`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `apt` or `apt-get` command to install applications. Anki is already in the Ubuntu repository, so several steps can install the application:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open `gnome-terminal`
2. enter the command `sudo apt install anki`, input your login password. After this command is executed, `anki` will be installed. You can press `win` key, then you can find it in the list of applications.

BTW: If you want to install any application, you can execute `apt search application-name` to search the application you require. If it found the application, use `sudo apt install application-name` to install it.

This is about [sudo](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/).

Answer (score 0):

To install programs on Ubuntu, you can either use the terminal or the "Software" app.

**Install programs from command line**

1. Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Copy and paste this command (to update package lists with the latest version info):

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Copy and paste this command to install Anki:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install anki
   ```

**Install programs from Software**

1. Click the icon for Software.

[image]

2. Type "anki" to perform a search:

[image]

3. Click Install.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can download Anki for Linux here:

https://apps.ankiweb.net/

Right-click on the tar file and extract it to somewhere. Next, go to the directory and open terminal in that address.

And you need only to type the following:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: my friend it worked thank you so much for the help!

Comment: The first sentence "there is no way, ones you download anki for your Linux form here:" does not make sense in English.

Comment: -1 This is a poor way to install programs. Use the package manager if you can (`apt-get`). `make install` will litter files all over your system, which are difficult to remove later. It will also prevent automated upgrading. If you must `make install`, e.g. because the repositories have an older version, at least use `checkinstall`, so that the files are tracked by the package manager.